# Revert a Draft page to its original version

Tags: pages, draft

I recently went into my Main Page to make some changes, and my inexperience with the new block mode caused me to mess it up. However, I had saved the messed-up version as a Draft.

Now, I want to get rid of the draft and revert it back to where it was before I made those changes. But I can't find any way to get rid of the changes I had made, so now my page is stuck as a Draft because I can't publish it as it is.

If I can't revert my page back to the pre-Draft version, then I will re-build it.

I have learned too late to make a duplicate of a page before going in to muck with it. Lesson learned.

In the meantime, if there's a way to revert my page back to the pre-Draft version, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have revisions turned on or has that feature been turned off? This is a developer/programmer stack, I'm struggling to see how this is not end user support for people using WP Admin. Can you elaborate more on the technical/coding side of your question? If you're just an end user asking for help using the WP interface/editor you should go to the WordPress support forums instead

Comment: Ugh! I don't know what I was thinking. I didn't notice that this was a development stack. Sorry about that. I should have gone to WP's support forum. You can all just ignore this one.